# .Bootstrap UI together with jQuery mobile UI?

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

i already build a website using bootstrap UI . and now i want implement small portion in that website using jquery mobile .bootstrap use keyword role and jquery mobile use keyword data-role  so my question can use bootstrap and jquery mobile together . will it cause and conflict when using both in same page ?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no conflict and you can use the libraries together. Try to load only the Jquery UI components that you need, this can be done by building a custom jQuery UI js file asset. It would include jQuery UI core and components such as the DatePicker and Draggable. That way you keep your 3rd party libraries smaller and thus increase page load speed.